# What more does the code need to delete a node from a linked list successfully?

Tags: c, list, data-structures

I want to delete a given node from a linked list by the node's index number (serial number). So what I tried to do in my function is that, first I have taken the user input of the index number. Then I used two node type pointers `temp` and `current`. I started traversing the list with `current` and when the index number of the node matches with the user input, I tried to delete the node. So far it is correct. I am facing problem with the deletion logic. Here is the code I tried:

```
void delete_node(struct node **start,int index_no)
{    
    int counter=0;
    struct node *temp, *current;

    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current=*start;

    while(current->next!=NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        if(counter==index_no)
        {
            temp= current->next;
            free(current);
            /*I guess some code is missing here. Help me finding the logic.*/
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n The index number is invalid!!");
        }
    }
}
```

The commented portion lacks the deletion logic.
Also, I have a feeling that this code is not space and time-efficient. If it is so, please suggest to a way to make it more compact.

Comment: Why are you calling malloc() **twice** if you want to _delete_ ?

Comment: @wildplasser, One pointer to traverse the list and other pointer to catch the next node to connect to the previous node. Actually, I do not have any experience. Trying out myself!

Comment: If you want to delete a node by **index**, you cannot avoid the O(n) complexity that you have here.  But it's more normal to delete by **reference/pointer**, which is then O(1).

Comment: following up on @wildplasser s question, but reduced. Why are you calling `malloc()` **at all** in a linked list delete op ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, Looks like I am misinterpreting the concept here. What I understand is, I have to use `malloc` to let the newly created node type pointer have the capacity to retain one data part and another data part containing the address of the next node. So if I don't allocate memory in the `current` pointer, how can I traverse the list via it? Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: You don't **need** a `newly created node` (you are deleting, remember?) You only nead one or two pointers. (which you already have)

Comment: @wildplasser, Thank you very much. Now the concept has become clearer to me. So when I am adding a node, I have to retain the data part and the link part; so I need a new node for space. But when I am traversing or deleting, I need only the capability of a pointer, not nodes. Thank you. I am just learning you know, so there are so much errors!! :/

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well, it's only `O(1)` if you have either a doubly linked list, or you also have a reference/pointer to the predecessor of the node you want to delete. Otherwise, you still have to walk the list...

Comment: @twalberg how is having a dbl-link list in any way reducing the algorithm complexity from O(n) to O(1) ? Quantum pointer traversal?

Comment: @twalberg: You can just copy the payload and `next` pointer from `node->next` to `node`, and then free the original `node->next`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ah... I had not thought of that approach - which would definitely be useful for small nodes. May not be as appropriate for large complicated structures, though. Also, it would invalidate any external pointers to the node you're "moving", so I guess it depends on your actual problem domain...

Comment: @WhozCraig It wouldn't. But in the naive singly-linked list deletion algorithm, you need to know the predecessor node in order to adjust it's next pointer. If all you have is a pointer to the node you want to delete, you need to walk the list to find the predecessor. In a doubly-linked list, you have a pointer to the predecessor within the node itself...

Comment: @twalberg well sure, it saves you the house keeping of a single extra node pointer during the O(n) traversal operation at the price of  keeping twice the number of node pointers in each additional list node. If all you need is single-list forward only traversal, there is zero gain, and a lot to lose, all so you don't maintain a `prev` pointer that you don't need in the first place (see my answer on how you can do this with no prev pointer).

Comment: See [Deleting node from linked list by index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857457/deleting-node-from-linked-list-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you allocating two nodes in the delete function, then leaking their memory? It seems they should be initialized to `start` or one of its successors.

You also need to update the `next` pointer in the previous element and potentially also the `start` (head) of the list if the removed element was the first (ie. `index_no == 1`).

You also have an off-by-one error where the final node can never be deleted, because only a node with a `->next` pointer will be considered for deletion.

Suggested reading: [A Tutorial on Pointers and Arrays in C](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting from a linked list is actually:

- find the pointer that points to us
- (if found) make it point to our .next pointer instead
- delete our node.

In order to change the pointer that points to us, we need a pointer to it: a *pointer to pointer*. Luckily the first argument already is a pointer to pointer, it presumably points to the *head* pointer that points to the first list item.

```
struct node
{
  struct node *next;
  int num;
} ;

void delete(struct node **pp, int num) {
    struct node *del;
    int counter;

    for (counter=0; *pp; pp= &(*pp)->next) {
        if(counter++ == num) break;
        }

    if (!*pp) { printf("Couldn't find the node(%d)\n", num); return; }

    /* if we get here, *pp points to the pointer that points to our current node */

    del = *pp;
    *pp = del->next;
    free(del);
  }
```

Comment: I am sorry, but quite did not understand `for (counter=0; *pp; pp= &(*pp)->next) {
        if(counter++ == num) break;
        }` this part? Would you explain?

Comment: it is basically the same as your `if(counter==index_no)` The loop is also basically the same loop, but with fewer variables to maintain.